# How does a Channel ability work with my commander?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-commander

How does Channel ([the Kamigawa mechanic](https://scryfall.com/search?q=oracle%3Achannel+block%3Akamigawa), not the card) work when your commander has such an ability, such as [Arashi, the Sky Asunder](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bArashi%2c%20the%20Sky%20Asunder%5d)?  Can I use it from the command zone? Do I pay the tax when I use channel? Does it increase when I use channel?

Answer (score 10):

You cannot use channel from the command zone. Channel is an ability that has both a mana cost, and the requirement to **discard the card**. Discarding a card is only from your hand, not from the command zone.

This means you need to somehow get your commander into your hand ([such as with](https://scryfall.com/search?q=o%3Aput+o%3A%22command+zone%22+o%3A%22into+your+hand%22) [Command Beacon](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bCommand%20Beacon%5d) or [Road of Return](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bRoad%20of%20Return%5d)). Once they're there you can activate their Channel ability and discard them, and this wouldn't involve the commander tax since it doesn't involve casting your commander from the command zone.

Comment: I added a second paragraph to your answer. I hope that's OK.

Comment: @doppelgreener I was considering adding something along those lines, but it felt like it wasn't really necessary for the answer. Now that it's there, I'm not going to remove it though!

Comment: Worth noting that if you do discard your commander from hand, you can choose to put it in your command zone instead of your graveyard.

Comment: @GendoIkari and still be able to activate channel, correct?

Comment: @CollinB Correct; you still paid the cost of discarding it; even though the card was put into command zone instead of graveyard.

Comment: The relevant rule for that is 118.11: "The actions performed when paying a cost may be modified by effects. Even if they are, meaning the actions that are performed don’t match the actions that are called for, the cost has still been paid."

Comment: @GendoIkari Than, in that case, what is the difference between that and Elenda, the Dusk Rose's ability? Why is it that you need to put Elenda into your yard and not command zone to activate their ability?

Comment: Because "Dies" is defined as "put into the graveyard from play"; so it triggers specifically when it actually is put into the graveyard. There's 2 differences: Discarding for channel is a cost, not a triggered ability. And the cost is discarding; not actually having it in your graveyard.

Comment: @GendoIkari So then is discarding not defined as putting it into your graveyard from your hand? Does a card actually have to hit yard to count as being discarded? My intuition says no based on how madness works, but still...

Comment: In English, it's the difference between an action and a result. "Dies" is a result; "Discard" is an action. "Destroy" would be more analogous to "discard". To destroy a permanent is defined as moving it into the graveyard, yet you can still destroy it without moving it to the graveyard if something changes where it goes when it is destroyed.